# How to read an excel file from a exe file (which is generated by converting py file into exe using pyinstaller)?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I wrote a python code and converted it into a .py file. The python file reads an excel file (that could be updated.) I want to read a "cell" value from this excel file and then save it in another excel file. I want to convert the .py file to .exe. It gives me the error below:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

This is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.ExcelFile('H:\filepath\file_name.xls')
df_sh1 = pd.read_excel(df, 'Sheet1')

XXX=df_sh1.iloc[14,3]

report=pd.ExcelFile('H:\filepath\report.xlsx')
report_sh1= pd.read_excel(report, 'Sheet1')


report_sh1_updated.iloc[4,5]=XXX

report_sh1_updated.to_excel("report_updated.xlsx")
```

More information.

- I used [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)
- Python Version: 3.7.4
- For converting py to exe, I put the py file in a new folder and then run the cmd in that folder and then ran the pyinstaller by pyinstaller yourprogram.py

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library ***openpyxl*** to read/write the .xlsx files and use the library ***csv*** to read the .xls file. I have a script with the same features.

Comment: Does it help in making an exe file?

Comment: @PouyanEbrahimi, it worked as exe file from pyinstaller.

Comment: I can edit the updating part, the first part is hard without open the doc in my computer. '''    import openpyxl

    book = openpyxl.load_workbook('H:\\filepath\\report.xlsx')
    sheet = book.active
    sheet.cell(row=4, column=5).value = XXX
    book.save('H:\\filepath\\report.xlsx')'''

Comment: It gave me the same error when I tried to make an exe file from the py file.

Comment: Is it working as py file?  If yes, reinstall the pyinstaller! case it keep the same error, change how you are reading the xls file.

Comment: @PouyanEbrahimi, use the pyinstaller like this ==> **pyinstaller yourprogram.py --onefile --windowed** .